# Как сохранить base64 файл?

Tags: php

Распарсиваю почту.
Файлы там разумеется в формате base64.
Делаю так

```
$file = imap_fetchbody($connect, $count, 2);//в этой части аттач
$file=base64_decode($file);
```

Чтобы сохранить использую

```
file_put_contents('',$file);
```

Как этот файл сразу отправить(не кодируя и не сохраняя)?

Comment: Отправить куда?

Comment: на сервер. На дропбокс допустим.

Comment: Если я получаю просто файл, не в виде base64, то делаю так $f = fopen($_FILE['filename']['tmp_name'], "rb"); и отправляю. А как отправить в этом случае?